# NIB Loads On Simulator But Not On Device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nib

Simply, my application's view loads in the simulator, all views intact.

When pushed onto the iPhone, the views fail to load. If it makes a difference, my iPhone 4 is jailbroken, but other applications I've created load with no problem on the phone.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is working on the simulator but not on the device a good starting point for debugging is the filename. 
The default filesystem on Mac OS is not case-sensitive, but the filesystem on the device is case-sensitive.

So please check if the filename used in your code matches exactly the actual filename.

Comment: I've heard this solution before, so I'll leave it here for someone else... But, I ended up reseting my phone using the home and lock buttons, restarted XCode, deleted the application, and then hit "Build and Go". Works now :/

Comment: I guess deleting the application did the trick - maybe you've implemented something that made the data in `Documents` not compatible anymore and your code started crashing. That's what's happening to me from time to time. I doubt it was crashing because of loading a NIB.

Comment: Scratch that. It's still not working. - What's super strange is that "viewDidLoad" is still being called... but the views from the view controller aren't loading. I really haven't any idea what could be causing this... *sigh.

Comment: Okay. Simply created a new XIB file, and recreated the same interface. Named it the same as the old file and deleted the old file. - Works now... Who knows...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was what you recommended; delete the app from device (in my case, iPad2), and reboot. Restart Xcode, and now I'm working.

I had a very similar issue to you; except, a version of my XIB was loading which was quite old. Device is properly provisioned, localization is set to what I expected, and yet still an old copy of the XIB was loading. I thought it was my XIB file too... and hated to have to recreate the XIB.

I don't know, I guess it was just holding onto something.

My iPhone4 and iPhone3G had no issues.